# Implications of $NL=P$

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, nondeterminism

What would be some implications of [$NL$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL_(complexity))$=P$? Would it be possible to get recommendations on good sources/papers I can read to learn more about this? Thank you

Comment: No, Non deterministic logarithmic space. I believe implications of P=NP is widely available.

Comment: That's what I thought, but someone tried to 'correct' this into 'NP'. Let me clarify this.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [consequences of $NC=P$](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/nc-p-consequences). This is a weaker statement, but more widely discussed (parallelism of P-complete problems).

Answer (score 1):

$NL = P$ means that every language in $P$ can be decided by a nondeterministic Turing machine using at most $O(\log n)$ space, where $n$ is the size  of the input.

Savitch's theorem states for all $f(n) \in \Omega(\log n)$: $NSPACE(f(n))\subseteq SPACE(f(n)^2)$.

Therefore $NL = P$ implies that every language in $P$ can be decided by a deterministic Turing machine using at most $O((\log n)^2)$ space.

Comment: This is true but I think the question is really looking for more just "If NL=P then everything fact about NL is also true of P."