# What would be the consequences if P=NL

Tags: complexity-theory

I haven't found anything in the literature that suggests what would happen if that is the case.
Thank you,
Akash

Answer (score 3):

$NL=P$ is not considered likely by the experts.

I found a few SE questions on this topic: [[1]](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89763/implications-of-nl-p) [[2]](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/nc-p-consequences)

The corollaries include:

> $P\subseteq L^2$ by Savitch's theorem
>
> $NC=P$ by the Squeeze theorem
>
> $EXP=PSPACE$ by $P\subseteq polyL$

I would like to include or exclude $P=L^k$, $k\in[1,2]$, but I have not collected sufficient evidence for or against that conclusion.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning $P \subsetneq PSPACE$ as a new separation.